# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

Perhaps mark my post as a duplicate, I searched but can not find answer to my problem, I have tried everything I saw the answers of the other post, but still gives me the same error: Fatal error: Call to a member function format () on a non-object in ... This is the code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Movimientos Cancelados del Mes.xls"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$server = "192.168.1.240";
$info = array("Database"=>"Ariel","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $info);
$param = array('ReturnDatesAsStrings'=> true);
$opt = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$per = $_GET["periodo"];
$eje = $_GET["ejercicio"];
$mov = 'Movimiento';
$est = 'Estatus';
$cli = 'Cliente';
$rfc = 'RFC';
$tot = 'Total';
$fec = 'Fecha Timbrado';
$uuid = 'UUID';
$cert = 'Certificado SAT';
$sql = "select v.MovID as '$mov',v.Estatus as '$est',v.Cliente as '$cli',cte.rfc as '$rfc',(v.Importe+v.Impuestos)as '$tot', c.UUID as '$uuid',c.noCertificadoSAT as '$cert', c.FechaTimbrado as '$fec'
from Venta V join CFD c on v.MovID = c.MovID join cte on v.cliente = cte.cliente 
where V.Estatus = 'Cancelado' and c.Periodo = '$per' and c.Ejercicio = '$eje' and  c.Empresa = 'MGJ' 
order by FechaEmision";

var_dump($fec);

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if( $query === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}

$campos = sqlsrv_num_fields($query);

$i = 0;

echo "<table border=''><tr>";
echo "<th>$mov</th>";
echo "<th>$est</th>";
echo "<th>$cli</th>";
echo "<th>$rfc</th>";
echo "<th>$tot</th>";
echo "<th>$uuid</th>";
echo "<th>$cert</th>";

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {

    $mov = $row['Movimiento'];
    $est = $row['Estatus'];
    $cli = $row['Cliente'];
    $rfc = $row['RFC'];
    $tot = $row['Total'];
    $uuid = $row['UUID'];
    $cert = $row['Certificado SAT'];
    $fec = $row['Fecha Timbrado'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$mov."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$est."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$cli."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rfc."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$tot."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$uuid."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$cert."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fec->format("d/m/Y")."</td>";

}

echo "</table>";
   sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

And look and look on the internet, but I find it gives me the error, the funny thing is that only some results are showing with the error, there are some that if printed on screen but after some lines, gives the error it may be at first, it may be near the end of the query, ignore the first few lines of code, is for export to Excel ... The error is marked on the line 75 which is:

```
echo "<td>".$fec->format("d/m/Y")."</td>";
```

Comment: Just FYI, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection....

Comment: @Hackerman thanks for the observation, it is only an internal site

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: just like @Fred-ii- pointed, you need to first declare a `DateTime` object like: `$myDate = new DateTime($fec);` and with that done, then use the `format` method: `$myDate->format("d/m/Y");`....Vamos Ricardo, no nos hagas quedar mal....saludos de Chile :)

Comment: ^ esattamente (scusi, parlo italiano solamente, ma capito spagnola un po) saludos de Canada ;-)

Comment: @Hackerman I already did that but now I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime :: __ construct (): Failed to parse time string (Date Timbrado) at position 0 (F): The timezone Could not be found in the database

Comment: @Fred-ii- L'italiano è come gli spagnoli, è possibile scrivere in italiano, se si desidera

Comment: [Excuse me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCzsX-LqJ-4)? ;)

Comment: jaja @Don'tPanic sorry

Comment: @RicardoRomero si, ma non posso adesso. Don't Panic caught us *lol*.

Comment: @RicardoRomero can you show us what value(s) is in the `Fecha Timbrado` column? Sidenote: It's not good practice to have named columns with spaces as they tend to be problematic. It's best to use underscores.

Comment: Maybe you have you dates in another format...I think the object expects a date time string in English format(like yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss)...and I think that you have something like `30/09/2016` or something like that in your DB...

Comment: In the Date column, there are values like these: "2016-05-02 14:48:24.000"

Comment: And @Fred-ii- the correct column name is "FechaTimbrado" as you can see in the query

Comment: @RicardoRomero `$fec = 'Fecha Timbrado';` and `$row['Fecha Timbrado']` you need to remove the spaces from them then. I.e.:  `$fec = 'FechaTimbrado';` and `$row['FechaTimbrado']`

Comment: But as I said @Hackerman, some results appear, some not, is strange, sometimes if you return the date and put it in the format, for example, when I check the date of July 2016, just bring me 26 results, after that, I get the error PHP and change the date format

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is only an alias to print the result

Comment: That's what I thought and those aliases might be playing tricks on you and using quotes around them. I don't know what else I can add to all this really. Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Here, you can see what I say about the results https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zppckreyyfmpnb/Captura.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I can see now whats going on, some of the results in the column FechaTimbrado are NULL values, do you know how can I print the NULL value? @Fred-ii-

Comment: End of the mystery!

Comment: @Hackerman it's not solved yet, the error still, how can I print the NULL in the same column? :/ I'm not a programmer...

Comment: @RicardoRomero You can try adding `IF NULL` in the SELECT. Or `if($row['x'] == NULL){...}` or use a ternary operator.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, you can use an if for that...

Comment: @Fred-ii- something like this? If (! empty($variable))
echo($variable);
else
echo ('NULL');

Comment: @RicardoRomero sure, give it a try. However and keep in mind that `!empty()` and NULL (0 is also considered as NULL) are two different animals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that worked for me, thanks for your time!

Comment: @RicardoRomero You're welcome Ricardo and glad to hear it. I posted a (community wiki) answer below which you can mark as solved in order to let everyone know that the question has been solved, *salute!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki, since it was solved in comments with multiple suggestions to the OP.

```
If (! empty($variable)) echo($variable); else echo ('NULL');
```

being the final solution to the problem.